# Collect same keys (by only the first part of the key) in a python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with similar keys and I want to collect all keys (and values) with the same **first part** (name or title in this case) into a dict or list in order to find the most common values afterwards. As a side-note: I don't know how many copies of a key (with the same first part) exist. Here are 3, but there could be only 2 or more than 3.

```
{'name=a=AA': (2, 2), 'name=a_copy=AA': (3, 3), 'name=a_copy2=AA': (3, 2), 
 'title=b=AA': (1, 2), 'title=b_copy=AA': (3, 3), 'title=b_copy2=AA': (1, 2)}
```

Is this possible? I though about using `key.split("=")[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the key-values and collect them into a dictionary with lists:

```
results = {}
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    prefix = key.partition('=')[0]
    results.setdefault(prefix, []).append((key, value))
```

This splits of the first part using `str.partition()`; this is faster for the single-split case. You could use `key.split('=', 1)[0]` as well, however.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key in D:  # this is the original dictionary
...     d[key.split("=")[0]].append(key)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'title': ['title=b_copy2=AA', 'title=b_copy=AA', 'title=b=AA'], 'name': ['name=a=AA', 'name=a_copy=AA', 'name=a_copy2=AA']})
```

Answer (score 0):

ِAnother way is to use the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) method and group the keys according to first item of `split` over `=`:

```
>>> d
{'name=a=AA': (2, 2), 'name=a_copy2=AA': (3, 2), 'title=b=AA': (1, 2), 'name=a_copy=AA': (3, 3), 'title=b_copy=AA': (3, 3), 'title=b_copy2=AA': (1, 2)}
>>>
>>> dd = {}
>>> 
>>> for k,v in groupby(d, key=lambda s:s.split('=')[0]):
    if k in dd:
        dd[k].extend(list(v))
    else:
        dd[k] = list(v)
>>> dd
{'name': ['name=a=AA', 'name=a_copy2=AA', 'name=a_copy=AA'], 'title': ['title=b=AA', 'title=b_copy=AA', 'title=b_copy2=AA']}
```